# Cannot download any plugins with PhpStorm - "Read Timed Out"

Tags: windows, powershell, plugins, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I cannot download any plugins via PhpStorm. When I select a plugin and click **install**, I get the following error:

[image]

Here is what happened in idea.log:

```
    2017-11-11 17:14:39,589 [ 499601]   WARN - Settings.impl.PluginDownloader - Cannot download 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=net.rentalhost.idea.laravelInsight&build=PS-172.4155.41&uuid=ab043267-0a5e-4706-a6f2-491a1a1b9b78': Read timed out 
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?action=download&id=net.rentalhost.idea.laravelInsight&build=PS-172.4155.41&uuid=ab043267-0a5e-4706-a6f2-491a1a1b9b78': Read timed out
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:362)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader$1.process(PluginDownloader.java:245)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader$1.process(PluginDownloader.java:242)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.lambda$doProcess$0(HttpRequests.java:414)
    at com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager.runWithUntrustedCertificateStrategy(CertificateManager.java:349)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:414)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:394)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:60)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:262)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader.a(PluginDownloader.java:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginDownloader.prepareToInstall(PluginDownloader.java:142)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.a(PluginInstaller.java:243)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.a(PluginInstaller.java:131)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginInstaller.prepareToInstall(PluginInstaller.java:70)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerMain$5.run(PluginManagerMain.java:432)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:718)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.openConnection(HttpRequests.java:505)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$300(HttpRequests.java:60)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getConnection(HttpRequests.java:288)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.getInputStream(HttpRequests.java:297)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:358)
    ... 27 more
```

I have already tried adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to VMOptions, this did not work, same for IPv6.

I have also already tried running `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable` in the elevated PowerShell, but also nothing happened.

Comment: Any proxy used? Also try using non-secure connection in `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Updates` -- may help (esp if proxy is involved somewhere later). P.S. Not sure how disabling stateful FTP will help for HTTP(s) downloads...

Comment: As last resort -- you can always download and install plugins manually from plugins website (although using built-in functionality is much better) -- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/phpStorm (note: no need to unzip any archives).

Comment: @LazyOne Using non-secure connection solved the problem. Thanks for the help.